# acortamiento de URL con htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Quiero acortar mi url para que sea mas "amigable" para los usuarios, por ejemplo:
aplicacion.com/Architecture/project/ejemplo/estadoCuenta/

Architecture y project son directorios que contiene los proyectos, "ejemplo" es el directorio de un proyecto y estadoCuenta es una sección, mi objetivo es acortar la url a: aplicacion.com/ejemplo/estadoCuenta/

Este es mi codigo htaccess que se encuentra adentro de la carpeta "ejemplo" dentro del proyecto.

```
#OCULTAR RUTA DE ARCHIVOS
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /Architecture/project/ejemplo/
RedirectMatch "^/Architecture/project/(.*)" "https://aplicacion.com/$1"

# ELIMINAR EXTENSION .PHP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# URL AMIGABLES
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)src/controllers/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/controllers/index.php [L]
```

alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

La redirección que deseas se logra con:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ejemplo/estadoCuenta/(.*)$ Architecture/project/ejemplo/estadoCuenta/$1 [L]
```

Estas reglas redirigirán cualquier URL que coincida con "aplicacion.com/ejemplo/estadoCuenta/" a "aplicacion.com/Architecture/project/ejemplo/estadoCuenta/".

El (.*) en la regla capturará cualquier texto adicional y lo anexará a la URL redirigida.